# Вопрос по поводу рекламы admob в приложении

Tags: admob, android

Если я приложение ещё не загрузил в Play Market, но добавил туда рекламу, и вот сейчас запускаю своё приложение на телефоне, чтобы проверить, но никакой рекламы там нету, она появится только после того, как я загружу своё приложение в Play Market?

Comment: а если всё четко по инструкции, никаких ошибок в идентификаторов ТОЧНО нет, размеров блока хватает, но выдаёт ошибку ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR и ничего не отображается ни на одном из устройств. Вообще не понятно куда копать.

Answer (score 2):

Реклама должна показываться, проверяйте правильность id и баннера. 
 Добавьте листенер и пропишите логи, чтобы проверить наличие или отсутствие ошибок.

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
  @Override
  public void onAdLoaded() {
    // Вызывается если загрружен
  }

  @Override
  public void public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode){
    //Вызывается, когда не удается выполнить запрос. Возможные коды ошибок:
    //AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR
    //AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST
    //AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR
    //AdRequest.ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL
  }

});
```

Comment: В манифесте есть, всё что нужно.
В методе OnCreate() добавил:

        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

Comment: layout: 

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_publisher_id"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

там все элементы размещены в Relative Layout

Comment: скорее всего, у вас ключ admob_publisher_id неправильный, при таком раскладе ошибки нет и баннера тоже. И, как по мне, adSize SMART_BANNER лучше вписывается в экран, чем BANNER.

Comment: Старые коменты удалите. id вы получили в admob или из примера?

Comment: взял из admob

Comment: вот, что в логе нашёл 

W/Ads﹕ Not enough space to show ad. Needs 360x50 dp, but only has 260x610 dp.

Я решил проблему, просто было мало места, спасибо большое за помощь!